# Rsyslog not sending data to logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, rsyslog

I have followed this [Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-centralize-logs-with-rsyslog-logstash-and-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-14-04#step-3-%E2%80%94-configuring-the-centralized-server-to-receive-data) to send logs to logstash via rsyslog.

But I am not getting logs in logstash. I am sending logs to a centralized rsyslog-server, and then to logstash. This rsyslog-server and logstash are on the same machine.

This is the /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf file on rsyslog-client :-

```
*.*                         @xx.xx.xx.xx:514
```

I have added this line at the top, rest is the same

This is the /etc/rsyslog.conf file on rsyslog-server,

```
# provides UDP syslog reception
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514")

# provides TCP syslog reception
module(load="imtcp")
input(type="imtcp" port="514")
```

I have enabled these modules, rest is same as default. Below is the file, /etc/rsyslog.d/01-json-template.conf

```
 template(name="json-template" type="list") {
constant(value="{")
  constant(value="\"@timestamp\":\"")     property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339")
  constant(value="\",\"@version\":\"1")
  constant(value="\",\"message\":\"")     property(name="msg" format="json")
  constant(value="\",\"sysloghost\":\"")  property(name="hostname")
  constant(value="\",\"severity\":\"")    property(name="syslogseverity-text")
  constant(value="\",\"facility\":\"")    property(name="syslogfacility-text")
  constant(value="\",\"programname\":\"") property(name="programname")
  constant(value="\",\"procid\":\"")      property(name="procid")
constant(value="\"}\n")
}
```

And the last is my output file config which sends data to logstash, it is also on the rsyslog-server machine,

```
*.*                         @127.0.0.1:5044;json-template
```

This below is my logstash configuration,

```
input {
udp {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    port => "5044"
    codec => "json"
    type => "rsyslog"
}
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    user => xxxxxxxx
    password => xxxxxxx
    index => "%{type}_index"
}
}
```

Still, with all this configuration, I dont see my rsyslog_index in elasticsearch. All the ports are up and running, there is no firewall issue also.

What and where is the problem ?

Comment: Depending on how things are being formatted, it may start working if you use the `json_lines` codec instead of `json`.

Comment: thanks for your support, but that did not work. I think problem is somewhere else.